# Hierarchical ldd(1)

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, gentoo, ldd

Due to using Gentoo, it often happens that after an update programs are linked against old versions of libraries. Normally, revdep-rebuild helps resolving that, but this time it's a dependency on a python library, and `python-updater` won't pick it up.

Is there a "hierarchical" variant of `ldd` which shows me what shared library depends on which another shared library? Most of the time libraries and executables are linked only against a handful of other shared libraries, which in turn were linked against a handful, turning the library dependency into a big list. I want to know which dependency I've got to rebuild with the new version of another library that I upgraded.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are running Portage≥2.2 with `FEATURES=preserve-libs`, you should rarely ever need `revdep-rebuild` anymore as old `.so.`vers will be preserved as needed (though you still need to rebuild carefully, as stuff still goes kaboom when `libA.so.0` wants `libC.so.0` and `libB.so.0` wants `libC.so.1` and some binary wants both `libA.so.0` and `libB.so.0`).

---

That being said, what `ldd` does is to get the dynamic linker to do load the executable or library as it usually would, but print out some info along the way.  This is a recursive "binary needs library needs other library&hellip" search, because that's what the dynamic linker does.

I'm currently running Linux/ppc32; on Linux/x86, the dynamic linker is usually `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, and on Linux/x86_64, the dynamic linker is usually `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.  Here, I call it directly just to hammer in the point that all `ldd` is nothing more than a shell script that calls upon the dynamic linker to perform its magic.

```
$ /lib/ld.so.1 /sbin/badblocks
Usage: /sbin/badblocks [-b block_size] [-i input_file] [-o output_file] [-svwnf]
       [-c blocks_at_once] [-d delay_factor_between_reads] [-e max_bad_blocks]
       [-p num_passes] [-t test_pattern [-t test_pattern [...]]]
       device [last_block [first_block]]
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /lib/ld.so.1 /sbin/badblocks
        linux-vdso32.so.1 =>  (0x00100000)
        libext2fs.so.2 => /lib/libext2fs.so.2 (0x0ffa8000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0ff84000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0fdfa000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x0fdc0000)
        /lib/ld.so.1 (0x48000000)
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /lib/ld.so.1 /lib/libcom_err.so.2
        linux-vdso32.so.1 =>  (0x00100000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x6ffa2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x6fe18000)
        /lib/ld.so.1 (0x203ba000)
$ grep -l pthread /sbin/badblocks /lib/libcom_err.so.2
/lib/libcom_err.so.2
```

`/sbin/badblocks` doesn't list `libpthread.so.0` as a library dependency, but it gets pulled in by `libcom_err.so.2`.

Is your problem that `ldd` doesn't output a nice-looking dependency tree?  Use `ldd -v`.

```
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 LD_VERBOSE=1 /lib/ld.so.1 /sbin/badblocks
        linux-vdso32.so.1 =>  (0x00100000)
        libext2fs.so.2 => /lib/libext2fs.so.2 (0x0ffa8000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0ff84000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0fdfa000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x0fdc0000)
        /lib/ld.so.1 (0x201f9000)

        Version information:
        /sbin/badblocks:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
        /lib/libext2fs.so.2:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
        /lib/libcom_err.so.2:
                ld.so.1 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld.so.1
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/libpthread.so.0
                libpthread.so.0 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libpthread.so.0
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
        /lib/libc.so.6:
                ld.so.1 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld.so.1
                ld.so.1 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld.so.1
        /lib/libpthread.so.0:
                ld.so.1 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld.so.1
                ld.so.1 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld.so.1
                ld.so.1 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld.so.1
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.2) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
```

---

If you want, you can read the ELF headers directly instead of depending on the dynamic linker.

```
$ readelf -d /sbin/badblocks | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libext2fs.so.2]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcom_err.so.2]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
$ readelf -d /lib/libcom_err.so.2 | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [ld.so.1]
```

You can also [`man ld.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so) for other cute tricks you can play with `glibc`'s dynamic linker.

Comment: the tree section of `ldd -v` output shows only libraries with versioned symbols

Answer (score 120):

I see many interesting details but no direct answer to the question asked.

The 'hierarchical' version of `ldd` is `lddtree` (from `app-misc/pax-utils`):

```
$ lddtree /usr/bin/xmllint 
xmllint => /usr/bin/xmllint (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib64/libreadline.so.6
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5
            libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2
        libicui18n.so.49 => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.49
            libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/32/libstdc++.so.6
                ld-linux.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux.so.2
            libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/32/libgcc_s.so.1
        libicuuc.so.49 => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.49
        libicudata.so.49 => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.49
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1
        liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. Thanks for mentioning `lddtree`, I've been looking for a tool like this for quite a while.

Comment: nice one, I didn't know about it :)

Comment: lddtree is here: https://github.com/gentoo/pax-utils/blob/master/lddtree.py (and there's also a fork at https://github.com/ncopa/lddtree written in sh instead of python).

Comment: On ubuntu `sudo apt install pax-utils` to get `lddtree`

Answer (score 19):

I needed something like this, so I wrote [`tldd`](https://gitlab.com/miscripts/tldd), here it is showing its own library dependencies:

```
$ ./tldd ./tldd
./tldd
└─libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003687c00000)
  ├─libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003685000000)
  │ └─libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003684c00000)
  │   └─ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003684400000)
  └─libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003686c00000)
```

You can also use `ldd -v` to see all dependencies of all shared libs, but it doesn't show a hierarchical tree.

Comment: @erwin what prevented you getting it working?

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I'm not getting email from gitlab for that project, but I'll fix it later this month.

Comment: I just tried the latest update to `tldd` and it works great! Cool little utility!

Comment: I saw my boss using it today and I've never heard of it before. So it looks like it's been a hit.

Comment: For some libraries I am getting a slightly different dependency tree with `tldd` as compared to `lddtree` (pax-utils). Not sure which one is definitive.

Answer (score -2):

I was also going to suggest "readelf -d" but also ensure you build with LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed" if you don't already. This will make you hit this problem less often. Portage 2.2's preserve-libs is nice but I gather it was masked primarily because of it - it does have flaws.

Comment: The flaws are minor nowadays. While at it, I think I was supposed to take a closer look at them, like a month ago or something :P.