# How to find who is calling the shared library functions?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I have some C++ code in place, which internally uses multiple third party libraries. The code compiles fine but during execution it is failing to load some shared library(libintbasic.so). Given the condition, I can not install any library into the system, the only way out is to find which function is calling that library. How could I find that out who is calling that library (my code does not call that directly).

Comment: Find the line which causes the call using a debugger.

Comment: You may want to add the "linux" tag

Answer (score 1):

> I can not install any library into the system,

That appears to be a bogus claim: clearly you can copy your binary onto the system. Installing an additional library into the same directory is not much harder.

> How could I find that out who is calling that library

There are two cases to consider:

1. your binary or one of the libraries it is directly linked with links to `libintbasic.so`. Your binary will not run *at all*, or
2. your binary, or one of the libraries it is directly linked with calls `dlopen("libintbasic.so",...)` and fails when that `dlopen` fails.

Debugging the first case is often easiest by setting `LD_DEBUG=files,libs`. The dynamic loader will then tell you which libraries are being loaded, and why they are required.

Debugging the second case is easy with `gdb`: set a breakpoint on `dlopen`, and execute `where` and `info shared` commands every time the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the linking option -lintbasic, you will see all the functions that needs this library in the error messages. This is not clean but it should work fine.

Comment: Well, that's not really something which I wanted to do. I want to get rid of those functions which is calling that. I want to find out those functions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ldd utility recursively for find all dependencies between shared libraries.

The following link also may be useful: [Does ldd also show dependencies of dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064685/does-ldd-also-show-dependencies-of-dependencies/15064784#15064784)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.