# Does ldd show all recursive dependencies

Tags: unix, shared-libraries, ldd

Suppose I have a A.so file whose dependencies are found from ldd

```
#ldd A
[...]
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007faaf9722000)
libxyz.so.49 => /usr/lib64/libxyz.so.49 (0x00007faaf5689000)
```

Now does this mean that with the presence of libxml2.so.2 and libxyz.so.49 everything is set for me to use A.so. How about if libxyz.so.49 internally has a dependency on some libabc.so.2.

I want to clarify if that was so will libabc.so.2 get listed when dependency of A.so is found from ldd or will that be not reflected? If not then how can I find all inter-dependencies? Can a missing inter-dependency down the chain with a call going to it and absence of the same result into core/crash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ldd also show dependencies of dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064685/does-ldd-also-show-dependencies-of-dependencies)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15064784/6573902) ldd shows all dynamic libraries required for a given  binary to run the application. This includes the transitive dependencies you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it invokes the dynamic linker and checks for dynamic dependencies. note that manually loaded libraries with `dlopen` won't be shown.

You can use [LibTree](https://github.com/haampie/libtree) If you want to see the hierarchy of the library dependencies and the way they are dependent (`RPATH`, `runpath` etc.).

Example:
[image]