# Command for finding dependencies of an executable

Tags: c++, ubuntu, dependencies

If I have a shared library called `libAlpha.so`, then in Ubuntu I can find its dependencies by running the command `ldd libAlpha`.

Is there a similar command in Ubuntu to find the dependencies of an executable?

Comment: `ldd` works for executables too

Comment: Some executables *require* some plugins but load them at runtime using `dlopen` (so `ldd` won't show you that). You could also use `pmap` or `cat /proc/$(pidof executable)/maps` to understand the actually used shared libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ldd`works fine on executables too.

Just pass the path to the executable : `ldd /bin/ls`

Answer (score 2):

[`ldd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488527/hierarchical-ldd1) should work for executables.

You can also try [`readelf -d`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readelf%201) (shows only direct dependencies).