# Why dynamic linked binary shows hard coded SO name?

Tags: c++, c, linker, elf

Sorry it might be a stupid question.
I didn't link libaudit directly, but why its name shows in my binary?

Strings shows:

```
strings dataserver|grep libaudit
libaudit.so.0
```

readelf shows:

```
readelf -a dataserver|grep "Shared lib"
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsapcrypto.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaio.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnsl.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpam.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaudit.so.0]
```

What does it mean and is there anyway I can check why it is added into my binary?

Thanks

## Update

Thanks. I'm reading the links below and adding some more findings.
I find that libpam was linked and it requires libaudit.so.0

Check libpam.so.0

```
ldd /lib64/libpam.so.0
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7fdf000)
libaudit.so.0 => /lib64/libaudit.so.0 (0x00007ffff7b80000)   <-- libaudit
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffff797c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff7616000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffff7fe0000)
```

However, I have 2 binaries, both linked libpam.so.  For binary1, it list libaudit.so.0 as NEEDED, but for binary2, it doesn't.

binary1 (with libpam but not depends on libaudit.so.0):

```
readelf -d binary1|grep "Shared lib"
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsybcsi_core210.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsybcsi_profiler210.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsybcsi_propertiesconfig210.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsybcsi_openssl210.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaio.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnsl.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpam.so.0]       <--- libpam
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

binary2 (with libpam but and depends on libaudit.so.0):

```
readelf -d binary2|grep "Shared lib"
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsapcrypto.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaio.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnsl.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpam.so.0]       <--- libpam
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libaudit.so.0] <--- libaudit
```

It confused me a lot about the key word "NEEDED", when will a lib is "NEEDED" if it is not *directly* used?

Comment: Most likely one of those other shared objects needed it.  Check out this Q&As: [Hierarchical ldd(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488527/hierarchical-ldd1)

Comment: Thank you I'm reading it...

Comment: @Zippon Your update doesn't have enough info: are the two binaries linked with the same linker? Same link flags?

Comment: @EmployedRussian yes they're linked with same linker and flags. But as they're in different branches, there're some libs are different. Anyway, I checked the diffed libs, they have no reference to libaudit.so.... I'm wondering when will a shared lib marked as "NEEDED". As I can see the "libpam" need "libaudit", but why "libaudit" only needed by binary2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I find the cause.

It's due to some reference of "_edata" and "_end" in my code.
In libpam.so, it is not found but libaudit.so which is needed for libpam.so, it was found and linker resolved it, then add libaudit as "NEEDED".

And _end is exposed as follows from linker scripts –

_end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);

This means, we should be using “end” and not “_end” unless we PROVIDE “_end” with our own linker scripts.
So, the fix is to change _end (and all such related symbols like _etext and _edata) to end (and etext, edata) so that they will be resolved correctly from standard libc, avoiding any dependency on other shared objects like libaudit.so.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean

It means your binary depends on it.

> and is there anyway I can check why it is added into my binary?

Most likely the linker you used found that some *other* library on the link line depends on `libaudit`, and *automagically* added it in.

GNU-ld does this, and Gold doesn't (producing a steady stream of programs that have incorrect `Makefile`s and fail to link with Gold).

If you link with `-v` flag, you should see the actual link command, although it may be hidden by `collect2` or some such wrapper.

Running the link under `strace -fvs 1024 -e execve` will show the actual link command for sure.

Comment: `ld --as-needed`/`cc -Wl,--as-needed` to avoid gnu ld adding these indirect dependencies.

Comment: @ephemient The dependency is most likely *not* unneeded here.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question, can you take another look?